# Working with arbitrary numbers

Tags: c#, math, integer

I want to write a class which can handle numbers of an arbitrary length with simple commands such as `DD(10000000000,10000000000)` to show `20000000000`

I've found a list of the limits in C# for data types:

```
Data type                                     Maximum positive value
Int32                                                  2,147,483,647
UInt32                                                 4,294,967,295
Int64                                      9,223,372,036,854,775,808
UInt64                                    18,446,744,073,709,551,615
```

But what if my number, for example, is `20,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000`

How would I do it?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `System.Numerics.BigInteger`:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`System.Numerics.BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

> Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.